# How can I make curly braces appear as if on a new line in Visual Studio without changing the code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

## Make curly braces appear as if on a new line

There is a coding standard in our company that demands the starting curly braces not to be placed on a new line.

```
private bool ReturnTrue() {
            return true;
}
```

Is there a tool or a plugin for Visual studio that would make braces appear as if they were on a new line when they are actually on the same line?

Every solution I found actually changes the code.

Comment: It would probably be easier to just get used to it. I tend to just follow the style that either a) my company prefers or b) is the predominant style of a given language.

Comment: change the company.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama: I am using it and am used to it. But when I see a code with braces in a new line, my heart just sings differently.
Bartosz Olchowik: Sometimes it really makes me think about it:)

Answer (score 0):

I would consider discussing the code standards. The curly brace on the same line is a common standard for C/C++ code, but it's very uncommon for C#. So maybe people just took with them what they where used to when the transition was made to C#, without considering that a new language might prefer different standards. You wouldn't be using underscore_delimited_identifiers in C# either, would you?

Of course, everyone (and every company) is free to use their own standards, but when one uses the same (or similar) standards than what everyone else does in that language, it will be easier to understand and/or modify code from someone else, e.g. from third-party libraries you might be using.

Comment: I actually did try to discuss this topic.... unsuccessfully though.  Their argument was that it saves lines of code. It's hard to continue the discussion if this is the case when dozens of lines can be shown on the screen.

Comment: I personally think a clear structure is more helpful to visualize the code than more lines on the screen. And we're not having those tiny CRT screens from the past any more. Just my 2ct

Answer (score 0):

At first my code was like this:

[image]

If you don't want the curly braces to be on new lines try this:

Tools=>Options=>Text Editor=>C#=>Code Style=>Formatting=>New Lines=> Uncheck the options under `New line options for braces` according to your own needs (I unchecked all of them) => OK

At this time, click ctrl+k, ctrl+d.

My code will become like this:

[image]

Comment: Your variant actually changes the code, which OP doesn't want. OP wants an option that only makes the code _appear_ as if the braces are on a new line, without modifying the actual .cs file contents.